# Why is this particular class member in the below code is not initialized?

Tags: java

```
    class nonStatic1 {
        nonStatic2 n2 = new nonStatic2();

        nonStatic1() {
            this.print();
        }

        void print() {
            System.out.println("insidenonStatic1");
        }
    }


    class nonStatic2 {

        nonStatic2() {
            this.print();
        }

        void print() {
            System.out.println("insidenonStatic2");
        }
    }

class nonStatic3 {
    nonStatic1 n1 = new nonStatic1();

    nonStatic3() {
        this.print();
    }

    void print() {
        System.out.println("insidenonStatic3");
    }

}

public class NonStaticInitializationTest {
    nonStatic2 n2 = new nonStatic2(); // <-- Never initialized!!

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("initialising n3 through main");
        nonStatic3 n3 = new nonStatic3();
    }

}
```

Comment: FYI, the below is the output :

Comment: initialising n3 through main
insidenonStatic2
insidenonStatic1
insidenonStatic3

Comment: add that to the question, not in a comment. You are pointing to the initialization, your question makes no sense.

Comment: @Stultuske
Can you help me out?

Comment: I've put it in an answer, but this is quite basic, this you should know before trying to create and instantiate other classes.

Comment: `nonStatic2 n2` is non-static. `NonStaticInitializationTest` is never initialized -> n2 is never initialized.

Comment: I was reading the class initialization some days before, and thus I tried this code out. I figured out that the class members inside the classes nonStatic1, nonStatic2, and nonStatic3 got initialized, but the member inside the class NonStaticInitializationTest is never initialized.

Comment: Got it! @Stultuke. But the other members are also non static, but how do they get initialized ?

Comment: they get initialized because you initialize them in your main method, which is what you run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not initialized because it is an instance member of your `NonStaticInitializationTest`, meaning you will have to create an instance for that class in order for that member to exist.

As soon as you create that instance, your `nonStatic2` instance will be created, but currently, you are only working in your main method, which is a static member, and requires no instance of its class.

Comment: Got it!! well explained!, Thanks for helping me out Stultuske :)

Comment: if this answers your question, please accept the answer.